# multiple condition Median If formula

Tags: excel, if-statement, median

I'm trying to calculate the Median since a pivot table won't work.

I have a number of conditons that i need to fulfill so i need a

```
={median(if(and(A:A=A2,B:B=B2,C:C=C2,D:D=D2),T:T,"")}
```

type formula.

Columns A, B, C and D have the criteria and T has the value that I need the Median of.

I have been able to produce a median with just 1 variable, but i'm only getting #n/a when i try more.

I have seen that an AND function doesn't work with an Array, so is there another way that I can calculate the mean based upon 4 different conditions?

Any Help would be greatly appreciated!

Ed

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2):

Array formula do not like `AND` or `OR` so use `*` and `+` respectively to turn the `TRUE` and `FALSE` of each of the Boolean test to `1` and `0` respectively.

So with `*` if any are `FALSE` it will be `0` and turn the whole to `0`, where as with `+` if any are `TRUE` then it will be greater than `0` and the `IF` will return the `TRUE` result:

```
=median(if((A:A=A2)*(B:B=B2)*(C:C=C2)*(D:D=D2),T:T))
```

Comment: @edholiday if this worked then please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **Google Sheet** (*If not, you should :)* )

Above, can be achieved using combination of MEDIAN and FILTER functions.

**FILTER(range, condition1, [condition2, ...])**

```
=MEDIAN(FILTER(T:T, A:A=A2, B:B=B2, C:C=C2, D:D=D2)
```

It filters **T:T** based on the conditions provided next, then Median of the result is returned.